# Automatic Reference modification using bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I have a bib file with following text in `journal` tab

> Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, IEEE Transactions on

This is default text ieee xplore gives for each entry.

However i want it in this way as output:

> IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing.

Can anyone tell me a automatic way to do this ? As i have hundreds of entries and i don't want to do this manually.

Currently i am using this style:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{filename}
```

Comment: BibTeX bibliography styles do not, AFAICT, modify the contents of the `journal` field. If you want to change the way the field is output, you will probably need to change the input.

Comment: You can use search-and-replace in your editor or a command line programme such as `sed` to do the replacements, though. You don't need to modify each entry individually.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i have lot many entries with different text styles. Above shown was one example. Anyway i have to do this manually i guess.  Thanks once again.